# How can I extract Album Art from a track?

Tags: itunes, album-art

I'd like to use iTunes to extract Album Art into standard image formats (such as .png or .jpg), so that I can back them up in a location external to the iTunes library.  How can I do this in iTunes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. In iTunes select the song and press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to **Get Info**.
2. Go to the tab **Artwork** and press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the Artwork.
3. Open `Preview.app`.
4. Select **File → New from Clipboard** from the menu or press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
5. Save the file to a custom location. (`.png`, `.jpg`, `.pdf`, `.tiff`, ...)

Alternative for 3 to 5 : just select the artwork, and drag and drop on you desktop (or elsewhere) (it will copy the original file there; eg : if the file inside was a PNG, you'll have a PNG, if it was a JPG, you'll get a JPG)

Comment: Does not work for Apple Music tracks. Maybe because they are DRM protected or maybe modern Music app does not support the feature.

Comment: well, actually you could drag the image to an empty place in your finder/desktop, and done. Step 3-5 are not necessary.

Answer (score 5):

For completeness sake, in case anybody else comes searching for how to do the same thing on iTunes for **Windows**, here's the process:

1. In iTunes, select the song, right-click, and choose **Get Info**.
2. Go to the **Artwork** tab.
3. Then, **click & drag the artwork to your Windows desktop**.  It makes a file.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

(Alternative for MAC - inspired from the other two responses)

1. In iTunes select the song and press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
   to **Get Info**.
2. Go to the tab **Artwork**.
3. **select** the artwork you want (you can have more than one in a file), and **drag & drop it** on you desktop (*or elsewhere*) (it will copy the original file there; eg :
   if the file inside was a **png**, you'll have a **png**, if it was a
   **jpeg**, you'll get a **jpeg**)